# Windows integrity check

Tags: windows

is there any way to check and make sure that my windows installation is completely fine (i just had a BSOD and i just want peace of mind it wont happen again).

i am running windows 7, but i often give help to others so if there is any utility that works like this on another OS, post it.

(also does disk check do this, i have had troubles with the windows seven disk checker as part of the error described in KB975778)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides running chkdsk you can run Microsoft's **System File Checker** tool. I posted an except from Microsoft's description, but the complete source can be found at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

If a Windows Resource Protection (WRP) file is missing or is corrupted, Windows may not behave as expected. For example, some Windows functions may not work, or Windows may crash. The System File Checker tool (SFC.exe) scans for missing or corrupted system files and repairs them.

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i wanted. (by the way, my computer came out clean so yay... now all thats bugging me is why it BSODed but i guess if there is nothing wrong with windows and it doesn't BSOD again, i'm happy.)